# Adding GUI into the python scripts

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, tkinter, computer-vision

I've tried to add the GUI (tkinter) into my script, but to no avail. If anyone can help me, i would be so grateful. I'm using Python 3.6 and i think the latest opencv?

I have only started programming 2 weeks ago. So, kinda new into all this. Basically, I want to create a window that just pick the image from my folder and then process it through the script so that whenever i want to use another image, i don't have to change the script. I hope that make sense..

this is the script that i took from Chris Dahms from youtube, and managed to change it to what I want.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

import DetectChars
import DetectPlates
import PossiblePlate 

SCALAR_BLACK = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
SCALAR_WHITE = (255.0, 255.0, 255.0)
SCALAR_YELLOW = (0.0, 255.0, 255.0)
SCALAR_GREEN = (0.0, 255.0, 0.0)
SCALAR_CYAN = (255.0, 255.0, 0.0)

showSteps = False

def main():

blnKNNTrainingSuccessful = DetectChars.loadKNNDataAndTrainKNN()         

if blnKNNTrainingSuccessful == False:                               
    print ("\nerror: KNN training was not successful\n")    
    return                                                          

imgOriginalScene = cv2.imread("CAR/Malaysia/22.jpg")

if imgOriginalScene is None:
    print ("\nerror: image not read from file \n\n")
    os.system("pause")
    return 

if imgOriginalScene is None:                            
    print ("\nerror: image not read from file \n\n")    
    os.system("pause")                                  
    return

listOfPossiblePlates = DetectPlates.detectPlatesInScene(imgOriginalScene)           

listOfPossiblePlates = DetectChars.detectCharsInPlates(listOfPossiblePlates)        

cv2.imshow("imgOriginalScene", imgOriginalScene)            

if len(listOfPossiblePlates) == 0:                         
    print ("\nno license plates were detected\n")            
else:                                                   



    listOfPossiblePlates.sort(key = lambda possiblePlate: len(possiblePlate.strChars), reverse = True)


    licPlate = listOfPossiblePlates[0]

    cv2.imshow("Image Plate", licPlate.imgPlate)           
    cv2.imshow("Image Threshold", licPlate.imgThresh)

    if len(licPlate.strChars) == 0:                    
        print ("\nno characters were detected\n\n")      
        return                                       


     drawRedRectangleAroundPlate(imgOriginalScene, licPlate)           

    print ("\nlicense plate read from image = " + licPlate.strChars + "\n")      
    print ("----------------------------------------")

    writeLicensePlateCharsOnImage(imgOriginalScene, licPlate)     

    cv2.imshow("imgOriginalScene", imgOriginalScene)               

    cv2.imwrite("imgOriginalScene.png", imgOriginalScene)          



cv2.waitKey(0)              

return

def drawRedRectangleAroundPlate(imgOriginalScene, licPlate):

p2fRectPoints = cv2.boxPoints(licPlate.rrLocationOfPlateInScene)         

cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, tuple(p2fRectPoints[0]), tuple(p2fRectPoints[1]), SCALAR_RED, 2)       
cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, tuple(p2fRectPoints[1]), tuple(p2fRectPoints[2]), SCALAR_RED, 2)
cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, tuple(p2fRectPoints[2]), tuple(p2fRectPoints[3]), SCALAR_RED, 2)
cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, tuple(p2fRectPoints[3]), tuple(p2fRectPoints[0]), SCALAR_RED, 2)


def writeLicensePlateCharsOnImage(imgOriginalScene, licPlate):
ptCenterOfTextAreaX = 0                          
ptCenterOfTextAreaY = 0

ptLowerLeftTextOriginX = 0                         
ptLowerLeftTextOriginY = 0

sceneHeight, sceneWidth, sceneNumChannels = imgOriginalScene.shape
plateHeight, plateWidth, plateNumChannels = licPlate.imgPlate.shape

intFontFace = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX                  
fltFontScale = float(plateHeight) / 30.0                    
intFontThickness = int(round(fltFontScale * 2))        

textSize, baseline = cv2.getTextSize(licPlate.strChars, intFontFace, fltFontScale, intFontThickness)      


( (intPlateCenterX, intPlateCenterY), (intPlateWidth, intPlateHeight), fltCorrectionAngleInDeg ) = licPlate.rrLocationOfPlateInScene

intPlateCenterX = int(intPlateCenterX)          
intPlateCenterY = int(intPlateCenterY)

ptCenterOfTextAreaX = int(intPlateCenterX)         

if intPlateCenterY < (sceneHeight * 0.75):                                               
    ptCenterOfTextAreaY = int(round(intPlateCenterY)) + int(round(plateHeight * 1.6))   
else:                                                                                
    ptCenterOfTextAreaY = int(round(intPlateCenterY)) - int(round(plateHeight * 1.6))    


textSizeWidth, textSizeHeight = textSize               

ptLowerLeftTextOriginX = int(ptCenterOfTextAreaX - (textSizeWidth / 2))         
ptLowerLeftTextOriginY = int(ptCenterOfTextAreaY + (textSizeHeight / 2))         


cv2.putText(imgOriginalScene, licPlate.strChars, (ptLowerLeftTextOriginX, ptLowerLeftTextOriginY), intFontFace, fltFontScale, SCALAR_CYAN, intFontThickness)



if __name__ == "__main__":
main()

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Pre-processing stage

```
# Preprocess.py

import numpy as np
import math

# module level variables ##########################################################################
GAUSSIAN_SMOOTH_FILTER_SIZE = (5, 5)
ADAPTIVE_THRESH_BLOCK_SIZE = 19
ADAPTIVE_THRESH_WEIGHT = 9


def preprocess(imgOriginal):
imgGrayscale = extractValue(imgOriginal)

imgMaxContrastGrayscale = maximizeContrast(imgGrayscale)

height, width = imgGrayscale.shape

grayscaled = cv2.cvtColor(imgOriginal,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

imgBlurred = np.zeros((height, width, 1), np.uint8)

imgBlurred, otsu = cv2.threshold(grayscaled,125,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

imgThresh = cv2.medianBlur(otsu,5)

return imgGrayscale, imgThresh
# end function


def extractValue(imgOriginal):
height, width, numChannels = imgOriginal.shape

imgHSV = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)

imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(imgOriginal, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

imgHue, imgSaturation, imgValue = cv2.split(imgHSV)

return imgValue
# end function

def maximizeContrast(imgGrayscale):

height, width = imgGrayscale.shape

imgTopHat = np.zeros((height, width, 1), np.uint8)
imgBlackHat = np.zeros((height, width, 1), np.uint8)

structuringElement = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))

imgTopHat = cv2.morphologyEx(imgGrayscale, cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, structuringElement)
imgBlackHat = cv2.morphologyEx(imgGrayscale, cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, structuringElement)

imgGrayscalePlusTopHat = cv2.add(imgGrayscale, imgTopHat)
imgGrayscalePlusTopHatMinusBlackHat = cv2.subtract(imgGrayscalePlusTopHat, imgBlackHat)

return imgGrayscalePlusTopHatMinusBlackHat
# end function
```

Comment: Try and be more specific about what you are looking for and only include code the is directly relevant to your question. You'll get more useful answers as people will know what you need help with.

Comment: my bad, this is the first time I try to ask question here.. I want to add GUI to the script. I want to create a window that just pick the image from my folder and then process it through the script so that whenever i want to use another image, i don't have to change the script.

I hope that make sense.. I will edit the description again..
thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are wanting is a window to select a file then this should work.

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import tkSimpleDialog
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

master = Tk()
master.withdraw()
my_file = askopenfilename()
mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you, it works..but the for Python 3, just changed to tkinter, the third line changed to from tkinter import simpledialog and the fourth line changed to from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename and it should run..

thank you again for helping me

Answer (score 0):

i recommend Gtk3 for your GUI.
here's a simple Gtk window with button:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version( 'Gtk', '3.0' )
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Window( Gtk.Window ):
    def __init__( self ):
        Gtk.Window.__init__( self )
        self.connect( 'destroy', lambda q: Gtk.main_quit() )

        button = Gtk.Button( "Gtk.Button" )
        button.connect( "clicked", self.on_button_clicked )

        grid = Gtk.Grid( )
        grid.attach( button, 0, 0, 1, 1 )

        self.add( grid )
        self.show_all()

    def on_button_clicked( self, button ):
        print( "Gtk.Button was clicked" )

w = Window()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. I will try and use that in my project. and here i am tearing colleague's and my hair because i didn't have enough capability to get stuff done..thank you so much again..